# How to design a spherical wrist for a robot?

Tags: design, mechanisms

I need a spherical wrist - where last 3 DOFs have axes that intersect - for a 6DOF robot arm, but I can't imagine the mechanics of 3 servos + brackets with intersecting axes.

Is this even possible?

Any pointers / suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: It's called a 3-axis gimbal. Seems needless for a wrist though.

Comment: Yes its possible. Also by the way, mr Euler has proven that you can do all of this with repeating allready used axes. Which is how most robots do this

Comment: @DKNguyen Not mandatory, but If first the 3 joints are parallel and the last 3 axes intersect, there is only one inverse kinematic solution.

Comment: @joojaa Would you care to explain the design as an answer please?

Comment: @smirkingman actually if you cross you get 2 solutions (which might trivially coencide) per revolution plus 2 singularities (which suck).